# Linux software installation - override version of library in ./configure

Tags: linux, installation, dependencies, gnu-make, configure

I'm trying to install the software TinyOWS on a Linux computer. The source code is written in C programming language. I don't have much experience with installing C or C++ programs from source code on Linux. I read installation instructions, and it says that I must follow 3 steps after I unzip the source code folder:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

When I run ./configure, I get the following error:

```
checking for xml2-config... /usr/bin/xml2-config
checking for libxml2 version... 2.7.6
configure: error: You need at least libxml 2.8.0
```

This means that the software being installed requires version 2.8.0 of a library called libxml2 but my computer only has the 2.7.6 version. Unfortunately I found out that I cannot easily install the libxml 2.8.0 on my Linux distribution. The reason why the software TinyOWS that I'm trying to install requires libxml2.8.0 of the library is because libxml2.7.6 has a small bug. But most of the functionality  of the software is not affected by the bug.

So, here is my question:
What files do I have to edit or what command line options do I need to use If I want the ./configure command to use the library libxml2.7.6 instead of libxml2.8.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the [source](https://github.com/mapserver/tinyows), in the file `configure.in` replace the line:

```
AC_MSG_ERROR([You need at least libxml 2.8.0])
```

By

```
AC_MSG_NOTICE([You need at least libxml 2.8.0])
```

Then, do:

```
autoreconf -f -i -s
./configure
make
```

The `configure` step will not stop. But i think if the developpers have restricted this version of `libxml2` there must be a good reason.

Comment: The suggested steps worked and I successfully compiled and installed the TinyOWS software. Now for the software to work 100% correctly, I think I'll try to [apply a patch](http://mapserver.org/tinyows/libxmlschemagmlbug.html) to my current version of libxml2.7.6.